# how to convert binary string data into String in android

Tags: java, android

Can anybody give me some clue that how to convert binary string into a string(english). I have tried and googled so much but couldn't find an answer.

Here is my code:

```
InputStream iStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.map);
InputStreamReader input;
String line = "";
//char character[] = null;
//String res = "";
input = new InputStreamReader(iStream); 
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(input);

Log.i("Helloo i am above variable", "Variable");

try {
    line = bf.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("hello helloo", line.toString());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's 'guys' / not guyz (and really should be left out or inclusive to the female gender).  And it's couldn't not cudnt.  Yikes.

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code?

Comment: Binary data cannot be represented as a english string always because of non printable characters. Binary data is there for a purpose why do you want to represent it as string.?

Comment: for KevinDTimm i didnt ask you to find out my english mistakes.its my style.

Comment: actually Suresh i have a binary file of Anquet map which contains so many images tiles of maps. i have to read that map and get that images. but now i am finding it difficult to parse binary data into other primitive data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the constructor   `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset charset)` with `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` as `Charset`? However, if you try representing data which is other than a string, this won't give you any, except maybe something ugly or an error...

Comment: its a binary map file which contains all kind of data. need to parse that file into its orignal form.